# Efficient HTTP streaming in Firefox OS

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, firefox-os, tcpsocket

I need to handle an infinite HTTP response (with [`Transfer-Encoding: chunked`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) header).

This response contains a stream of images, so it must be handled as efficiently as possible.

`XmlHttpRequest` is **not** a solution here since it keeps all the reply in memory. Plus, if reading `ArrayBuffer`, the response isn't populated before the end of streaming, which means never here.

So, since I am under Firefox OS, the [`TCPSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) API seems to be my only hope.

I already started to implement a dirty HTTP stack ([here](https://github.com/eliemichel/fxos-AlphaRemote/blob/master/js/libs/Stream.js) and [here](https://github.com/eliemichel/fxos-AlphaRemote/blob/master/js/libs/HttpStreamParser.js)), getting inspiration from the IMAP/SMTP implementations but it is still **very** slow.

So, two questions:

1. Is it worth spending time on this, or did I miss something easier?
2. If I want to implement it, what are the best practices not to foget about?

PS: I communicate with an external device, so changes on the server side are just not possible here.

Comment: An example of a similar infinite request can be found in the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/processing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [the XMLHttpRequest doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), Firefox actually makes available extra `responseType` values (and so does Firefox OS) for streaming data, like `moz-chunked-arraybuffer`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest({ mozSystem: true });
xhr.responseType = "moz-chunked-arraybuffer";
xhr.open('GET', deviceStreamingUrl);
xhr.addEventListener('progress', event => {
  processChunk(xhr.response);
});
xhr.send();
```

Thanks to fabrice on #fxos@irc.mozilla.org!